# Best way to mentally calculate wind correction angle (WCA) when in a holding pattern?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures

I have been out of flying for a while and need to brush up on my holding patterns. I need a quick method or rule of thumb to calculate the wind correction angle (WCA) for example when flying outbound for a holding pattern.

Can anyone provide a quick mental method or rule of thumb?

Thanks

Comment: I understand the formulas but this is not practical during flight

Answer (score 1):

One holding pattern rule-of-thumb, shown in the FAA [Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf) , page 5-3-17, para. (c) is:

> (c) Compensate for wind effect primarily by
> drift correction on the inbound and outbound legs.
> When outbound, **triple the inbound drift correction** to
> avoid major turning adjustments; for example, if
> correcting left by 8 degrees when inbound, correct
> right by 24 degrees when outbound.

*(emphasis is mine)*

Of course this is just a rule-of-thumb subject to many variables. After you enter the holding pattern you should make any necessary adjustments to remain within the holding protected airspace.

If you have not been flying for a while, reading the entire section on "holding" in the AIM would provide you with an excellent resource to help refresh your knowledge.